# Upload a file to specific folder using WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I need help for how to upload a file in WordPress, I don't want to upload files into the default path of media files i.e. into `uploads/../..`, I want to upload my files into `wp-content/uploads/my_folder`, I just created one file in `wp-admin` folder and added some functionality there, from that form I want to upload my file (not creating plugin).

Is it possible to do like this? If yes then how? If no then what I want to do for uploading file?

I tried the following solution for it:

```
    $path_array  = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_path = $path_array['baseurl'].'/myfoldername/';
    $target_path = $upload_path."/".$file_name;
    $file_name = $_FILES['fieldname']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["fieldname"]["tmp_name"];

    upload_user_file($_FILES,$upload_path); // Called this function
```

In `functions.php` of my theme, I defined the above called function `upload_user_file()` like as follows:

```
function upload_user_file( $file = array(),$path) {
    if(!empty($file)) 
    {
        $uploaded=move_uploaded_file($file['fieldname']['tmp_name'],$path.$file['fieldname']['name']);
       if($uploaded) 
       {
           echo "Uploaded successfully ";
       }
       else
       {
            echo "Some error in upload ";
            print_r($file['error']);
       }
    }
}
```

Please help me for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have time to write out a complete answer for you, but here's some tips to get you going in the right direction: 1. Do not EVER modify files in the wp-admin folder - including adding files.  This is considered bad practice.  2. Please, use the built-in WP uploader, don't write your own uploader.  It's way, way, WAY better.  3. You can modify where uploaded files go using built-in WordPress hooks / actions / filters.  See this for more info: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-upload-dir/ and http://ernieleseberg.com/wordpress-custom-upload-directory/

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because of FILES array loses its values very soon..
Upload it in the same code where you called function it will work...

Thanks cale_b its really helpful.